# Nested Object Update issue in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Please check the following model class of `Team` and `Member`. In a team, there is `members` which can hold a list of `Member`. A JSON object is used to create and update teams in service methods. A member can be updated individually. In `Member` object, there is a property `lastSeenAt` which is updated according to that member's activity.

```
class Team: Object {
  dynamic var channelId: String? = nil
  dynamic var title: String? = nil
  let members = List<Member>()

  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "channelId"
  }
}

class Member: Object {
  dynamic var _id: String?
  dynamic var lastSeenAt: Date?
  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "_id"
  }
}
```

**Service Methods For updating teams and members**

```
func createAndUpdateTeams(_ teams: [[String:Any]]?) {

  DispatchQueue(label: "queueNameToCreate", attributes: []).async {          
      let realm = try! Realm()

      try! realm.write({ () in
        for team in teams! {
          realm.create(Team.self, value: team, update: true)
        }
      })
  }
}

func updateMember(_ member: [String:Any]?) {

  DispatchQueue(label: "queueNameToUpdateMember", attributes: []).async {
      let realm = try! Realm()

      try! realm.write({
        realm.create(MemberRealm.self, value: member, update: true)
      })
  }
}
```

To get the real-time update on teams, I have added a notification block on `Results<Team>` as follows:

```
teams = realm.objects(Team.self);
notificationToken = teams?._addNotificationBlock({ [weak self](changes) in
  switch( changes ) {
  case .initial:
    self?.tableView?.reloadData()
  case .update(_,let deletions,let insertions,let modifications):
    print("Modified: deletions: \(deletions.count),\n insertions: \(insertions.count),\n modifications:\(modifications.count)")
    self?.tableView?.reloadData()
  case .error:
    break
  }
})
```

**Problem**

When I called `updateMember(_:)` to update `Member` object, the notification block gets called. Though there is no update in the Team, the TableView load itself with same data. As a effect the screen fluctuates for each `updateMember(_:)` call.

**Github Sample Project to generate the issue**
https://github.com/milankamilya/RealmUpdateTest

Comment: Please include the actual code causing the error, especially the code used to update `lastSeenAt`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor updated.

Comment: That piece of code isn't really relevant. First of all, it doesn't show where `lastSeenAt` is updated (unless you don't update the property directly, you only update it when updating the whole object itself through `realm.create(MemberRealm.self, value: member, update: true)`. Secondly, you didn't show how/when you call the update methods.

Comment: Please see the [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sir, I am sorry for late response. I have created a repository in GitHub to reproduce the issue. https://github.com/milankamilya/RealmUpdateTest

Comment: Have you actually checked the page I linked??? Creating a whole project is not a __minimal__ example at all.

Comment: Yes Sir, but to explain the update issue, I had to create a example. I respect the value of your time. I had no other choice to explain issue. I think it is good way to reproduce the issue that I am facing. Please pardon me may be I am wrong.

Comment: Compiling, running and debugging a full Xcode project is not the way anyone will help you here on SO. Especially when they would even have to install pods. Create a minimal example that includes the problematic code and include it in your __question__, don't upload it to an external website.

Comment: Ok, @DávidPásztor

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sir, I updated the question. Could you please check?

Comment: Thanks for the update, now your question is clear. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor for cooperation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the intended behaviour of `Realm`. Notification blocks are called by design even if only a single object is updated in a one-to-many relationship of one of the objects that is in the scope of your completion block. Since your `Team` class has a one-to-many relationship to `Member`, when setting up a notification block on all `Team` objects, the notification block will be and should be called each time a `Member` object gets updated if it is in stored in one of your `Team` objects `members` property.

See [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3494) GitHub issue explained the issue in more details.

One workaround you could use is to define `members` as `LinkingObjects` instead of a `List`. I haven't tried this myself, but according to the answers on linked GitHub issue, the notification block doesn't get called when an object changes that is part of `LinkingObjects` in contrast to a one-to-many relationship using `List`.

To use `LinkingObjects` as `members`, you need to change your model classes the following way:

```
class Team: Object {
    dynamic var channelId: String? = nil
    dynamic var title: String? = nil
    let members = LinkingObjects(fromType: Member.self, property: "team") //finds all Member objects, where Member.team = self (this team)

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "channelId"
    }
}

class Member: Object {
    dynamic var _id: String?
    dynamic var team:Team?
    dynamic var lastSeenAt: Date?
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```